# For input string: Error

Tags: java

I have a csv file, which I am trying to export into database using java. I have a Builder column which I have labeled as String but my snippet blows up I do not know why this is happening and why I have the Integer.parseInt being displayed in the error even though I have the column labeled as a string. I am a novice in Java so would appreciate any assistance.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "McKenzie Homes"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Well it makes sense that it can't parse the string "McKenzie Homes" into an integer, right?

Please share your code so we can help.

Comment: Ask yourself this, is "McKenzie Homes" a number?

Comment: What would you expect when you try to convert `McKenzie Homes` to a number? 42?

Comment: But I do not know why is it trying to parse it into an integer? That is the baffling part to me. It is all text field no integers at all.

Comment: @JasonSmith, can you share the part of the code where you read from the 'column' and save it to the database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somewhere in your application Integer.parseInt() is being called. Might want to check where in the app it is being executed, and make sure that it does not get called on Strings.

Comment: Funny part is the snippet is blowing up on line 44 of the column and the first 43 lines are being exported to the database successfully.